# Why custom input validation and setError() won't work when using useField()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I have created a minimal version of the issue I am facing in a form. I want to have certain InputFields to have a max and min range. If the user types something outside that range, I am setting the error field using `setError()`. But, the validation does not always work. For example, if I type 555 in the CGPA field, I see the error, but I don't see it if I type 55, whereas I have specified the range to be from 0 to 4.

Code sandobox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-curran-098m4?file=/src/InputField.tsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this](https://formik.org/docs/api/field#validate) and [this](https://formik.org/docs/api/useField#fieldhookconfigvalue), I came up with the solution. The trick was to pass an object to `useField()` instead of just passing in the props like I was doing.

So, `InputField.tsx` should look like this:

```
function InputField({ color, ...props }: TInputFieldProps) {
  const [field, { error }] = useField({
    name: props.name,
    validate: (value) => {
      let message: string = undefined;
      if (props.type === "number" && (props.min || props.max)) {
        if (parseFloat(value) > parseFloat(props.max as string)) {
          message = `The value of ${props.label} cannot be more than ${props.max}`;
        }

        if (parseFloat(value) < parseFloat(props.min as string)) {
          message = `The value of ${props.label} cannot be less than ${props.min}`;
        }
      }
      return message;
    },
    type: props.type,
  });

  return (
    <FormControl
      error={!!error}
      style={{ marginTop: "10px", marginBottom: "20px" }}
    >
      <FormLabel htmlFor={props.name}>{props.label}</FormLabel>
      <Input
        {...props}
        {...field}
        id={field.name}
        inputProps={{
          min: props.min ?? props.min,
          max: props.max ?? props.max,
          step: props.step ?? props.step,
        }}
      />
      {error && <FormHelperText error={!!error}>{error}</FormHelperText>}
    </FormControl>
  );
}

export default InputField;
```

Although, I am still not sure why `setError()` bugs out like that. It is probably related to something that has to do with stale states.

To my testing, this does not break Yup validation if you are using Yup, which is fantastic. The reason I could not rely on Yup here was because the `min` and `max` values were coming from parsing a file upload in my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own custom validation function for that here is an example

Formik Field:

```
<Field
    type="number"
    name="myNumber"
    placeholder="Please input something"
    validate={(event) => Validators.customFieldLevelValidation(event, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(12)])} />
```

Custom Validator Class:

```
class Validators {
    static customFieldLevelValidation = (value, validations) => {
        for (let validation of validations) {
            const result = validation(value);
            if (result) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    };

    static maxLength = max => value =>
        value && value.length > max ? `Must be ${max} characters or less` : undefined;

    static minLength = min => value =>
        value && value.length < min ? `Must be ${min} characters or more` : undefined;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to achieve this without switching away from useField()?

Comment: Sorry for replaying this late, I guess you already resolved with useField() - @mahieyin-rahmun